# Windows 10 Powershell changes insertmode to overwrite after certain amount of characters

Tags: powershell, ssh, psql, overwrite

I ran into something really annoying regarding overwrite/insertmode. I've only observed this when I run psql (shell-client for postgres database) on a remote machine that i have accessed through ssh.

Problem: 
If I jump to the beginning of a line using ctrl+a or alt+left or alt+right or step back using just left arrow more than 14 characters, it automatically switches over to overwrite. Basically, I always have insertmode, but then when i step too far back in the buffer it changes behavior. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Turns out it's not overwriting per se, it only displays as if it's overwriting. That is, the actual command being modified is still interpreted by the client intact, as if I was using insertmode. However, it makes interfacing with my database a nightmare as whenever I want to edit a query I have to type "blind".

Comment: Did you try changing your keyboard? Also, it is possible to turn on `Insert` using the [Numpad zero](https://superuser.com/a/1203139/1131396)

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! It's not keyboard related unfortunately. It also does not happen locally in powershell, only when i remote to a different machine, and so far only in psql. I'm new to powershell as I normally work from *ix.

Comment: I think this is related to the built in ssh client within Windows 10. I've had the same "issues" in the past with ssh in Windows 10 (I used putty whenever I had to do a lot of things through ssh, for small maintenace stuff I just used the built in ssh client)

Comment: I added a comment that I got the same behaviour in Putty, but was mistaken. Removed the comment. Thanks bluuf for input.